# Assembly increment and loop

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, dos, bios

I want to know how to display an output like this using loop and incrementation using ASCII codes.

**Aa Bb Cc ... Zz**

This is my working code below, and it seemss, there is / are many mistakes. It becomes an endless loop.

Please check and help me.

Thanks.

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.code

main proc

    mov ah, 0      
    mov al, 12h   ; Clear screen
    int 10h

    mov ah,3    
    mov bh,0     ; get cursor
    int 10h

    mov ah,2      
    mov bh,0      ;set cursor
    mov dl,12
    int 10h


    mov cx, 5      ; counter


t1:


    Mov dl, 65    ; A   
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h

    add dl, 1


t2:

    Mov dl, 97    ; a
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h

    add dl,1

loop t2

loop t1

    mov ah, 4ch
    mov al,00h
    int 21h



endp
end main
```

Comment: I don't know what you had in mind with those two consecutive `loop` instructions, but you should probably look up `loop` in an instruction set reference and read about how it works.

Comment: Because, last program I made is loop and incrementation of A-Z...

Now, I want with small letters...

Comment: Ok. But you do realize that when the inner loop finishes, `CX` will be 0, which means that the outer loop never will finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    mov cx, 5      ; counter
    Mov dl, 65    ; A   

t1:
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h

    add dl, 32    ; 97 - 65 - convert to LC

    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h

    sub dl,31     ;remove the 32 added, but increment
    push dx       ;save DX on stack
    mov dl, 32    ;space character

    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h

    pop DX        ;return DX from stack

    loop t1
```

[Amended in the light of Michael's comment - `Add dl,1 became sub dl,31`]

(I've omitted your initialisation and termination which should be fine)

Your issues are:

*t1..t2* : load `DL` with `'A'` and output it; then increment
*t2..loop t2 instruction*: load `DL` with `'a'` and output it; then increment
      - do this 5 (contents of `CX`) times. Note you are loading `DL` with `'a'` each time
      - AND that `CX` will be decremented each loop, so the loop terminates when `CX` **BECOMES** 0
*loop t2*: Next, loop back to t1 and repeat until `CX` **BECOMES** 0.

So, at the `loop t1`, `CX` is already 0, and is thus decremented and the program loops back to t1, so `A` is output until `CX` once again becomes 0, 65534 loops later.

Comment: Thank you! 

But there is a problem, when I run the program, Aa is okay.

But others are not, others are displayed as symbols.

Comment: Try replacing the `add dl,1` with `sub dl,31`.